# Quicker & automated way to replicate mysql from master to slave

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, linux, mysqldump

I want to replicate around 60 databases from master to slave server. I've read this guide https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/get-mysql-replication-up-and-running-in-5-minutes/ and few other. It's manual and time consuming work. Is there a way to automate replication of all databases from master to slave?